# interpret/extract coefficients from factor variable in glmnet

Tags: r, extract, glmnet, coefficients

I have run a logit model through `glmnet`. I am extracting the coefficients from the minimum lambda, and it gives me the results I expect. However I have a factor variable with nine unique values, and `glmnet` produces a single coefficient for this, which is expected for a binary variable but not factor...

```
library(glmnet)
coef(model.obj, s = 'lambda.min')

#output:
TraumaticInj  2.912419e-02
Toxin         .           
OthInj        4.065266e-03
CurrentSTDYN  7.601812e-01
GeoDiv        1.372628e-02 #this is a factor variable w/ 9 options...
```

so my questions:

1) how should I interpret a single coefficient from a factor variable in `glmnet`?

2) is there a method to extract the coefficients for the different factors of the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Glmnet doesn't handle factor variables. You have to convert them to dummies using eg model. Matrix.  So the results you are seeing is glmnet treating your factor variable as a single real variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done, b/c glmnet doesn't treat factor variables. This is pretty much answered here: [How does glmnet's standardize argument handle dummy variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887747/how-does-glmnets-standardize-argument-handle-dummy-variables)

This comment by @R_User in the answer is particularly insightful:

> @DTRM - In general, one does not standardize categorical variables to
>   retain the interpretability of the estimated regressors. However, as
>   pointed out by Tibshirani here:
>   statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso/fulltext.pdf, "The lasso method
>   requires initial standardization of the regressors, so that the
>   penalization scheme is fair to all regressors. For categorical
>   regressors, one codes the regressor with dummy variables and then
>   standardizes the dummy variables" - so while this causes arbitrary
>   scaling between continuous and categorical variables, it's done for
>   equal penalization treatment. –  R_User Dec 6 '13 at 1:20

Comment: I liked very much your answer; would be great if you add some code, e.g how to treat the variable as a dummy variable; or say, making a model.matrix ...