# Steps for building a formula interface for existing function in R?

Tags: r, interface, package-development

There are many R functions out there but only some of them have a standard formula interface (see e.g. this question: [Formula interface for glmnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093868/formula-interface-for-glmnet)). I think in general formula interfaces are a good way to standardize R functions and provide a consistent user experience.

**My question**
Is there an authoritative reference how to build a formula interface for a given R function and/or can you give an overview of the steps to do this? I hope that you don't have to program everything from scratch... Thank you

Comment: this is possibly too broad/off topic (looking for off-site resource) for SO, although I do think it's interesting. https://developer.r-project.org/model-fitting-functions.html might be a good place to start

Comment: @BenBolker: Why should this be too broad? You yourself just gave a very good reference... Thank you!